Python не видит команду
Я установил библиотеку (telebot), но команду (import telebot) он не видит и считает неверной
Использую PyCharm, самая новая версия

Покажите хоть, что написали и как ругается(текстом, не картинкой)

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
